# SQL Server 2008 full-text index issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, fulltext-index

I have a `TableA` as specified below in which a full-text index is specified for column `Name`

**TableA**

```
Id (PK)
Name (TXI)
```

The table has the following records:

```
ingrid
neville
ned
audry
inga
```

I then run the following query against the table:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'"n*"');
```

The result of the query is as follows:

```
Id         Name
1          ingrid 
2          neville
3          ned
```

Why is it returning the first record even though it doesn't starts with 'n'?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'n*');
```

Comment: Doing that will get me no records

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your full-text index is out of date.  Does rebuilding it fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

By following the Jim B suggestion try to update your catalogue by:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG TableA REORGANIZE
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE CONTAINS(Name,'"n*"');
```

Another tip: **The purpose of Full-Text is searching for WORDS inside a text** so i dont know if you are testing the full-text but to get what you are looking for, they right way is the operator `LIKE` as:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Name LIKE 'n%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query works for me....:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE FTS_Demo_2

INSERT  FTS_Demo_2 (Document) VALUES ('ingrid')
INSERT  FTS_Demo_2 (Document) VALUES ('neville')
INSERT  FTS_Demo_2 (Document) VALUES ('ned')
INSERT  FTS_Demo_2 (Document) VALUES ('audry')
INSERT  FTS_Demo_2 (Document) VALUES ('inga')

/* WAIT FOR AUTO POPULATION TO POPULATE */

SELECT  * FROM FTS_Demo_2 WHERE CONTAINS (Document, '"n*"')
```

Results:

```
RecordID    Document
----------- --------------------
2           neville
3           ned

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Maybe it's a problem with your FTS Index or Catalog?  What are your column types?  I made the column in this example NVARCHAR(MAX), and this is the catalog properties:

[image]